# RTMP Authentication for Wowza

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, wowza

I have a java encoder that currently does not support RTMP authentication.

I've done some research on how to implement that part this days but the RTMP protocol lacks of documentation regarding this and I couldn't find anything (very helpful) related to this.

Basically I have the following url schema: rtmp://user:pass@wowza_adress:1935/application

In the official documentation (V1.0) released by adobe there is no specification of any authentication command nor any RTMP authentication reference.

Could someone give me an hint/example on how this should be done ?

Comment: RTMP authentication is considered propitiatory, and adobe never released an official spec.

Comment: @szatmary I know that. But surely somebody did some reverse engineering and found out how it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach for this after a long study, was to look at librtmp C code, and go from there.